# How to calculate mean from importing data from textfile into densevector python spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have created below code to calculate the mean values.

I have input data like

> empname,age,salary
>   a,10,100
>   b,20,200
>   c,30,300
>   d,40,400
>   e,50,500

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '2g')
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
text_file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/trial/emp_data.txt")
parts = text_file.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
p1 = parts.map(lambda p: int(p[2]))
rdd = sc.parallelize([Vectors.dense(p1.collect())])
cStats = Statistics.colStats(rdd)
cStats.mean()
```

I have made the RDD for column salary and passing to the `[Vectors.dense(p1.collect())]`, but I am getting output as `[100.0,200.0,300.0,400.0,500.0]`.  But it should be `300`.

Comment: `parts.map(lambda p: int(p[2])).mean()`

Comment: Thanks for Reply,I can also calculate by using parts.map(lambda p: int(p[2])).mean()  but I just wanted to pass output of p1 (P1.collect() =[100.0,200.0,300.0,400.0,500.0] to dense vector and to apply mean on this array via  cStats.mean() but I am getting same only [100.0,200.0,300.0,400.0,500.0] the output should be [300.0]

Comment: No, it shouldn't. What you're doing doesn't make sense. You create a RDD with a single "row" and five columns so result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
from statistics import mean

data = '''
a,10,100

b,20,200

c,30,300

d,40,400

e,50,500
'''

li = re.findall(r',(\d+)$',data,re.MULTILINE)

print(mean(map(int,li)))

300.0
```